# Process multiple input type file one by one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

How can I convert a multiple input type file form element, to make as many post requests as there are files?

To be clearer:

Imagine I want to asynchronously submit each file in parallel to the server, even if the user selected multiple fies in the filechooser dialog?

I think I cannot split the user's file selection and recreate the inputs as this would be a security breach browser-side...

Any idea how to do that?

In the end, the idea is to have an uploader where some uploads can be aborted but not all of them. even if they originate from the same file selection.
And to have upload progress for each post (using a php peck module called uploadprogress)

Comment: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Im aware of this plugin and have used it in the past, but thanks. This doesn't apply here. I'm using  server side solution to calculate the progress. it's about how I initialise the uploads

Comment: You can't make multiple posts at the same time using native file input form elements. You have to use a client-side uploader plugin to do what you want. In addition to the one already suggest, look at PLupload.

Comment: Something like this? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/ and then loop each `<input type="file">` and AJAX it to the URL your need? maybe, I've never done it. Looks like it will be available to people with modern browsers.

Comment: @jszobody *"You have to use a client-side uploader plugin"* since when are plugins required?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Comment: the answer in the linked question shows how to do it with 1 file, but it should be easy to adapt to a multiple file input.